# How to match similar filenames and rename so that diff tools like Beyond Compare see them as a pair to perform a binary comparison?

Tags: filenames, string-matching, similarity, file-comparison, filecompare

I'm looking for the best approach to comparing files that I believe are identical but which have different filenames. Comparison tools like BeyondCompare are great but they don't yet handle different filenames - when comparing files in separate folders they attempt comparisons with the files that have the same name on either side.

(I don't work for or have a financial interest in BeyondCompare, but I use the tool a lot and find it has some great features).

There is MindGems Fast Duplicate File Finder for matching files in any location throughout several folder trees that have different names but this is based on CRC checks I believe, I am using this tool but I am only gradually trusting it, so far no faults but don't trust it as much as BeyondCompare yet. BeyondCompare offers the complete piece of mind of doing a full binary compare on the file.

In my case the files tend to have similar names, the difference being ordering of the words, punctuation, case differences and not all words present. So it's not easy to use a regex filter to match the files that some diff tools like Beyond Compare already provide because the file substrings can be out of order.

I'm looking for a way to match similar filenames before renaming the files to be the same and then 'feeding' them to a tool like BeyondCompare. Solutions could be scripts or perhaps in the form of an application.

At the moment I have an idea for an algorithm (to implement in Perl) to match the filenames to suit my problem whereby the filenames are similar as described above.

Can you suggest something better or a completely different approach?

1. Find a list of files with the exact same filesize
2. Make a hash of alphanumeric substrings from first file, using
   non-alphanumeric characters or space as delimiter
3. Make a hash of alphanumeric substrings from second file, using
   non-alphanumeric characters or space as delimiter
4. Match occurrences
5. Find which file has the highest number of substrings.
6. Calculate a percentage score for the comparison on the pair based on
   number of matches divided by the highest number of substrings.
7. Repeat comparison for each file with every other file with the exact
   file size
8. sort the pair comparisons by percentage score to get suggestions of
   files to compare.
9. Rename one file in the pair so that it is the same as the other. Place in separate folders.
10. Run a comparison tool like BeyondCompare with the files, folder comparison mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already have Fast Duplicate File Finder Pro, this outputs a text report of the duplicates in CSV and XML format.

I will process the CSV to see the groupings and rename the files so that I can get beyond compare to do a full binary comparison on them.

**Update:**

And here is my code. This Perl script will look at each pair of files (in the directories/folders being compared) that are the same and rename one of them to be the same as the other so that the two folders can be run through Beyond Compare which will do a full binary compare (if the flatten folders option is switched on). Binary compare confirms the match so that means that one of each duplicate pair can be purged.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 

use strict;
use warnings;


use File::Basename;

my $fdffCsv = undef;

# fixed
# put matching string - i.e. some or all of path of file to keep here e.g. C:\\files\\keep\\ or just keep
my $subpathOfFileToKeep = "keep";
# e.g. jpg mp3 pdf etc.
my $fileExtToCompare = "jpg";

# changes
my $currentGroup = undef;
my $group = undef;
my $filenameToKeep = "";

my $path = undef;
my $name = undef;
my $extension = undef;
my $filename = undef;

open ( $fdffCsv, '<', "fast_duplicate_filefinder_export_as_csv.csv" );

my @filesToRenameArray = ();

while ( <$fdffCsv> )
{
  my $line = $_;

  my @lineColumns = split( /,/, $line );

  # is the first column and index value
  if ( $lineColumns[0] =~ m/\d+/ )
  {
    $group = $lineColumns[0];

    ( $line ) =~ /("[^"]+")/;
    $filename = $1;

    $filename =~ s/\"//g;

    if ( defined $currentGroup )
    {
      if ( $group == $currentGroup )
      {
        ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '\..*"' );

    store_keep_and_rename();
      }
      else # group changed
      {
        match_the_filenames();

    ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '\..*"' );

    store_keep_and_rename();
      }
    }
    else # first time - beginning of file
    {
      $currentGroup = $group;

      ( $name, $path, $extension ) = fileparse ( $filename, '\..*"' );

      store_keep_and_rename();
    }
  }
}

close( $fdffCsv );

match_the_filenames();

sub store_keep_and_rename
{
        if ( $path =~ /($subpathOfFileToKeep)/ )
      {
        $filenameToKeep = $name.$extension;
      }
      else
      {
        push( @filesToRenameArray, $filename );
      }
}

sub match_the_filenames
{
    my $sizeOfFilesToRenameArraySize = scalar( @filesToRenameArray );

        if ( $sizeOfFilesToRenameArraySize > 0 )
    {
      for (my $index = 0; $index < $sizeOfFilesToRenameArraySize; $index++ )
      {
        my $PreRename = $filesToRenameArray[$index];

        my ( $preName, $prePath, $preExtension ) = fileparse ( $PreRename, '\..*' );
        my $filenameToChange = $preName.$preExtension;

        my $PostRename = $prePath.$filenameToKeep;

        print STDOUT "Filename was: ".$PreRename."\n";
        print STDOUT "Filename will be: ".$PostRename."\n\n";

        rename $PreRename, $PostRename;
      }
    }

    undef( @filesToRenameArray ); @filesToRenameArray = ();

    $currentGroup = $group;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Beyond Compare can do that.
Just select the file on the left and the file to compare on the right.
Choose 'compare' or use the align function (right mouse button)

Comment: Yes, but those are manual steps. From my question, I want Beyond Compare to automatically recognise, for comparison, many pairs of files with similar names in the first place.